# How many colorings of a cyclic graph with bounds on adjacent colors?

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

Let $C_{2n}$ be the cyclic graph with $2n$ edges. Number the vertices in consecutive order as $\{ v_1,\dots,v_{2n} \}$. We are given two colors, say red and blue, and color every vertex of $C_{2n}$ in such a way that:

- there are no singletons, that is every vertex $v_i$ has the same color as either $v_{i-1}$ or $v_{i+1}$ (or both),
- there are at most $n$ consecutive vertices of one color, that is if $\{ v_i,\dots,v_{i+k} \}$ all have the same color, then $k \leq n-1$.

> How many such colorings are there?

Here are two things I've attempted:

- *A counting argument.* Let's say we color the first vertex $v_1$ blue and the last vertex $v_{2n}$ red. With this imposed, the number of colorings is related to the partition number of $2n$, but with two restrictions imposed: the size of every part is between $2$ and $n$, and there are an even number of parts. Let $P(2n)$ be this number. (I am not sure whether there is a useful expression for this, I've only seen partition numbers with different restrictions.) Now of course $v_1$ and $v_{2n}$ could have the same color, so even assuming $P(2n)$ has some useful expression, it's not clear to me how this leads to an answer.
- *A recurrence argument*. I've also attempted to find a recurrence relation, based on the following observation. Let $C_{2n+2}$ be given some admissible coloring. Remove exactly one vertex from the two largest groups of consecutive monochromatic vertices. This yields an admissible coloring of $C_{2n}$. It's not clear how to get a useful recurrence relation from this, as there is a choice to be made when there are more than two longest monochromatic chains. One could condition on their number (or their sizes), but I'm not sure that would help.

Comment: What have you tried? I suggest you sketch all the possibilities for one or two small examples and see if you gain any insight in how to proceed. Or post your attempt at solving the problem and ask specific questions instead of basically "What is the answer?"

Comment: @SteveKass All right - the information that you asked for is in the last paragraph.

Comment: Your counting argument can be used to build a part of the solution, the other part is when the color of $v_1$ and $v_{2n}$ is same, for this you create a set $m$ where $m \le n-2$ containing adjacent vertices, which also have $v_1$ and $v_{2n}$  in it, The calculation of number of this $m$ set is nothing but ways of splitting $m-2$ into $2$ equal groups. then you again do the partition of $2n-m$ vertices into an odd number of parts. But I'm guessing you want something involving less calculation

Comment: I'll be posting an answer later tonight when I get home.

Comment: @joriki Have you been able to find an argument?

Comment: @LeoMoos: Sorry it took a bit longer – I already had the argument and the sum form, but then I realized there are closed forms for the sums and I didn't finish working them out last night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related not to partitions (unordered sums) but to compositions (ordered sums) of $2n$.

Your approach of pre-colouring two neighbouring vertices and then counting the possibilities for the remaining vertices seems like a good one to me, since it breaks the circular symmetry that makes it difficult to use stars-and-bars counts otherwise.

So let’s start with your first case of two neighbouring vertices, say, $1$ and $2n$, being coloured differently. What you write about the restrictions isn’t quite correct, since each of these two vertices has to be followed by at least $1$, not $2$, vertices of the same colour. Let’s pre-colour those two vertices, $2$ and $2n-1$, as well. Now each pair of pre-coloured vertices can be followed by any number (including $0$) of vertices of the same colour. Let $k$ be the number of additional changes from red to blue and back (additional to the one that necessarily exists). Then we have $2k+2$ monochromatic runs (bins) to fill with $2n-4$ vertices (balls), of which $2$ runs can contain any number of vertices and the remaining $2k$ runs must each contain at least $2$ vertices. So fill each of those $2k$ runs with $2$ vertices each; that leaves $2n-4-4k$ vertices to be distributed without restrictions over the $2k+2$ runs. That can be done in $\binom{2n-4-4k+2k+2-1}{2k+2-1}=\binom{2n-2k-3}{2k+1}$ ways. Thus the number of admissible configurations is

$$
\sum_k\binom{2n-2k-3}{2k+1}
$$

for $n\ge2$. Here and in the following, it doesn’t matter precisely which upper limit we put on such sums because the terms are $0$ in an entire range from $k\sim\frac n2$ to $k\sim n$; in order not to distract from the essential content with irrelevant details, I won’t write explicit upper limits; sums over $k$ (and later over $j$) will always run from $0$ up to the point where the binomial coefficient first becomes zero. (We can’t extend the sums to $\infty$ because the binomial coefficient eventually becomes non-zero again when its upper index becomes negative.)

For vertices $1$ and $2n$ being coloured the same we can perform a similar count. Now we don’t need to pre-colour any additional vertices, since we already have $2$ consecutive ones of the same colour. If there are $k$ additional changes from red to blue and back (additional to the one that necessarily exists), there are $2k+3$ runs to fill with $2n-2$ vertices, of which $2$ runs can contain any number of vertices and the remaining $2k+1$ runs must each contain at least $2$ vertices. So fill each of those $2k+1$ runs with $2$ vertices each; that leaves $2n-2-2(2k+1)$ vertices to be distributed without restrictions over the $2k+3$ runs. That can be done in $\binom{2n-2-2(2k+1)+2k+3-1}{2k+3-1}=\binom{2n-2k-2}{2k+2}$ ways, so the number of admissible configurations is

$$
\sum_k\binom{2n-2k-2}{2k+2}\;.
$$

In both cases, there are $2$ ways to choose the colours for the pre-colouring, so we have to add these two results and multiply by $2$. But in that total we haven’t yet taken into account that at most $n$ consecutive vertices may have the same colour, so we need to subtract the count of the configurations that violate that restriction.

Since there can’t be more than one run that causes such a violation, that’s not too difficult. If the inadmissible run has length $\ell\lt2n-1$, there are $2n$ ways to place it. Then we can fill the remaining $2n-\ell$ vertices with $2k+1$ runs of at least $2$ vertices each, in $\binom{2n-\ell-2(2k+1)+2k+1-1}{2k+1-1}=\binom{2n-\ell-2k-2}{2k}$ ways. Thus, we counted

\begin{eqnarray}
2n\sum_{\ell=n+1}^{2n-2}\sum_k\binom{2n-\ell-2k-2}{2k}
&=&
2n\sum_k\sum_{\ell=n+1}^{2n-4k-2}\binom{2n-\ell-2k-2}{2k}
\\
&=&
2n\sum_k\binom{n-2k-2}{2k+1}
\end{eqnarray}

inadmissible configurations per colour of the inadmissible run. Thus, altogether there are

$$
a_n=2\left(
\sum_k
\left(
\binom{2n-2k-3}{2k+1}
+
\binom{2n-2k-2}{2k+2}
\right)
-
2n\sum_k\binom{n-2k-2}{2k+1}
\right)
$$

admissible configurations. [Here’s Java code](https://github.com/joriki/math/blob/master/info/joriki/math/stackexchange/Question4665529.java) that computes this sum and checks that it matches a direct enumeration. These are the values up to $n=16$:

\begin{array}{r|r}
n&a_n\\\hline
1&0\\
2&4\\
3&6\\
4&12\\
5&60\\
6&226\\
7&672\\
8&1884\\
9&5166\\
10&14004\\
11&37620\\
12&100226\\
13&265408\\
14&700116\\
15&1842198\\
16&4839228
\end{array}

This isn’t in OEIS.

To find closed forms for these sums, consider the generating function

$$
s_m(q)=\sum_j\binom{m-j}jq^j\;.
$$

It satisfies the recurrence relation

\begin{eqnarray}
qs_m(q)+s_{m+1}(q)
&=&
q\sum_j\binom{m-j}jq^j+\sum_j\binom{m+1-j}jq^j
\\
&=&
q\sum_j\binom{m+1-j}{j-1}q^{j-1}+\sum_j\binom{m+1-j}jq^j
\\
&=&
\sum_j\left(\binom{m+1-j}{j-1}+\binom{m+1-j}j\right)q^j
\\
&=&
\sum_j\binom{m+2-j}jq^j
\\
&=&
s_{m+2}(q)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

For $q=1$, this is $s_{m+2}(1)=s_{m+1}(q)+s_m(q)$, the recurrence relation of the Fibonacci numbers $F_n$, so with $s_0(1)=s_1(1)=1$ we have $s_m(1)=F_{m+1}$.

For $q=-1$, this is $s_{m+2}(1)=s_{m+1}(q)-s_m(q)$, and with $s_0(-1)=1$ and $s_1(-1)=1$ this yields the values $1,1,0,-1,-1,0,\ldots$, which can be summarized as $s_m(-1)=\frac2{\sqrt3}\sin\left(\frac{(m+1)\pi}3\right)$.

This allows us to obtain

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_k\binom{m-2k}{2k}
&=&
\sum_j\binom{m-j}j\frac{1+(-1)^j}2
\\
&=&
\frac{s_m(1)+s_m(-1)}2
\end{eqnarray}

and

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_k\binom{m-(2k+1)}{2k+1}
&=&
\sum_j\binom{m-j}j\frac{1-(-1)^j}2
\\
&=&
\frac{s_m(1)-s_m(-1)}2\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Applying this to the expression for $a_n$ above yields

\begin{eqnarray}
a_n
&=&
2\left(\sum_k\binom{2n-2-(2k+1)}{2k+1}+\sum_k\binom{2n-2k}{2k}-1-2n\sum_k\binom{n-1-(2k+1)}{2k+1}\right)
\\
&=&
s_{2n-2}(1)-s_{2n-2}(-1)+s_{2n}(1)+s_{2n}(-1)-2-2n(s_{n-1}(1)-s_{n-1}(-1))
\end{eqnarray}

and thus

$$
\bbox[5px,border:1px solid black]{a_n=F_{2n+1}+F_{2n-1}-2n\left(F_n-\frac2{\sqrt3}\sin\frac{n\pi}3\right)-4\sin^2\frac{n\pi}3\;.}
$$

Comment: Wow, this is terrific, thank you very much!